# C# Error in readering XML from URL

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML reader but I receive an error when I'm trying to read the XML from an URL (external source).

This is the code I have ATM:

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://dl.bukkit.org/api/1.0/downloads/projects/craftbukkit/view/build-1330/");
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {

        }
```

Very simple code, but it returns an error which says:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Any idea?
I can't edit the XML, because it's not mine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the Xml doc look like if you try to access it from your web browser?

Comment: It's not Xml, it's Json.

Comment: @Phil This might be a noob question, but is it hard to read Json in C#? I'm still a little bit new...  EDIT: Because when I read the file via WebClient I get an unformatted file back.

Comment: I don't know much about Json deserializers.  I'm sure someone will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to analyze the response returned by the sever, you'll see, that you get JSON instead of XML. You can add a parameter to the URL to get XML:

```
http://dl.bukkit.org/api/1.0/downloads/projects/craftbukkit/view/build-1330/?format=xml
```

Comment: So what this does is it converts the page to XML? It seems to work tho :).

Comment: You have three options here. First, you can set the `Accept` header to  `text/xml`, which seems to be a little bit tricky with the `XmlReader`. Second, you can add the parameter which is a feature of the API you are using and therefore isn't standardized. Third, you can parse the JSON returned by the web service using the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) or other third-party components (which would be the fastest approach of the three).

Comment: Json seems a little bit hard for me :(, I think im going with the second option, the parameter. But I'm going to look at the third option for sure, thanks!